# Fluently Hibernate DB2SQLConfiguration

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I need a configuration for a DB2 Fluently SessionFactory.
For PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc. Classes are available, see example, but how can I integrate DB2?

```
public class SessionFactory
{
    public static ISessionFactory create()
    {
        var config = Fluently.Configure();

            config.Database(PostgreSQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(c => c
            .Host("localhost")
            .Database("local")
            .Username("adm")
            .Password("adm")
            .Port(5432)));          

        config.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));

        config.ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema);

        return config.BuildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.DB2Configuration`](http://fluentnhibernate.org/api/FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db/DB2Configuration.htm):

```
config.Database(DB2Configuration.Standard.ConnectionString(c => c
    .Server("db-srv")
    .Database("tables")
    .Username("toni tester")
    .Password("secret")
    ));
```

See FluentNHibernate's [DB2ConfigurationTester](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/master/src/FluentNHibernate.Testing/Cfg/Db/DB2ConfigurationTester.cs) unit test class for different configuration implementations for DB2.